# Install apc in production environment

Tags: php, alternative-php-cache

Executing a `pecl search apc` returns the following:

```
Package Stable/(Latest) Local
APC     3.1.14 (beta)         Alternative PHP Cache
```

And according to here: http://pecl.php.net/package/APC `3.1.14` is still beta. So, should I go ahead and install that version, or stick to the latest stable version?

Edit:

Actually is going to go live, the server, in a day or less

Comment: If it actually works, then use it. But I can tell you from several years of experience that APC is one of the most buggy pieces of software I have ever seen; it was responsible for nearly constant php-fpm crashes over several supposedly "stable" versions, and these crashes haven't been fixed. I finally had to switch to eAccelerator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use 3.1.14 in your development environment and everything is working as expected, I would use the same versions in your production environment. This result in the best possibility to prevent unforeseen errors.

If you are planning on using a stable (or any other different) version in your production environment: first test it in your development environment!